# How to check if QLPreview is loaded?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I have `QLPreviewView` and I need to check if the preview is loaded in `n` seconds after assigning `QLPreviewItem`. `QLPreviewView` and `QLPreviewItem` don't have any events for loading and any fields to check it, so I came with checking view hierarchy. It works pretty good with my few test cases, but ofc hierarchy can be changed in new versions of mac OS. Another solution could be working with field `displayState`. It's always nil when preview isn't loaded, but it can be nil when preview is loaded (for example for folder preview which doesn't have state). So even if we have `displayState` equal to nil, we still need to check if file can own any preview state at all, i.e. this solution depends on concrete mac OS version too.

Is there any tricks which are better then observing view hierarchy? Or may be is there any alternatives to QLPreviews?

Comment: What's a case where the file exists but doesn't load?

Comment: @MortenJ I don't know such a case but some files need a long time to load. For example large text files. Some users can be confused by constantly spinning preloader.

Comment: Any solution for that? There is a function canPreview() for QLPreviewController. But I can not access it in MacOS